# autofocus not working if body is hidden?

Tags: html, autofocus

my login page has an input with "autofocus" property:

```
<input class="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" autofocus required="required" value="">
```

This works... But I would like to hide the body until it has completely been loaded:

```
<body style="visibility: hidden;" onload="$('body').css('visibility', 'visible');">
```

This also works, but now, the autofocus property seems to be ignored... Is there a way to make both autofocus and body/hidden working?

Thanks,
Fred

PS: sorry for my poor english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <input class="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" required="required" value="">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            setTimeout("$('.username').focus();", 500);

        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kJUD7/9/